# php mail function headers with attachment

Tags: php, email, html-email, email-headers

I'm not sure why but this has suddenly stopped sending out emails. I have tried to test the email server using `mail("email@domain.com","test","test message");` and it sends it fine. I have a feeling something is wrong with my headers?

I have tried to send it with and without attachments but it is not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

```
<?php

extract($_POST);

$dir    = '../uploads/';
$files_temp = scandir($dir, 1);

foreach ($files_temp as $key=>$value) {
  if (strpos($value,$file_id) !== false) {
      $files[] = $value;
  }
}

$message = "";

$message .= "Firm: " . $_POST['firm'] . "\n";
$message .= "Attorney: " . $_POST['attorney'] . "\n";
$message .= "Main Contact: " . $_POST['main_contact'] . "\n";
$message .= "Phone: " . $_POST['phone'] . "\n";
$message .= "Cell: " . $_POST['cell'] . "\n";
$message .= "Fax: " . $_POST['fax'] . "\n";
$message .= "Address: " . $_POST['address'] . "\n";
$message .= "Email: " . $_POST['email'] . "\n";
$message .= "Court County: " . str_replace("_"," ",$_POST['court_county']) . "\n";
$message .= "Court Name: " . $_POST['court_name'] . "\n";
$message .= "Case Type: " . str_replace("_"," ",$_POST['case_type']) . "\n";
$message .= "Appearance Type: " . $_POST['appearance_type'] . "\n";
$message .= "Date: " . $_POST['date'] . "\n";
$message .= "Time: " . $_POST['time'] . "\n";
$message .= "Department: " . $_POST['department'] . "\n";
$message .= "Case Name: " . $_POST['case_name'] . "\n";
$message .= "Case Number: " . $_POST['case_number'] . "\n";
$message .= "Your Client: " . $_POST['your_client'] . "\n";
$message .= "Client Present: " . $client_present_text . "\n";
$message .= "What do you want the attorney to accomplish at this hearing?: " . $_POST['text1'] . "\n";
$message .= "Explain case background: " . $_POST['text2'] . "\n";
$message .= "Signature: " . $_POST['signature'] . "\n";

// email fields: to, from, subject, and so on
$to = "email@domain.com";
$from = "email@domain.com"; 
$subject ="Appearance form"; 
$headers = "From: $from";


// boundary 
$semi_rand = md5(time()); 
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

// headers for attachment 
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

// multipart boundary 
$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";



// preparing attachments
for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
    $file = fopen($dir.$files[$x],"rb");
    $data = fread($file,filesize($dir.$files[$x]));
    fclose($file);
    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
    $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$files[$x]\"\n" . 
    "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$files[$x]\"\n" . 
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
}


// send
$ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Are you getting an error? Is the mail never arriving? Have you checked your smtp server logs? Have you checked your spam folders?

Comment: The mail is never arriving. It's not going into spam. I'll try checking the SMTP logs.

Comment: Try removing the `@` in front of your mail function if you don't see anything obvious in your smtp server logs. The `@` suppresses errors in PHP.

Comment: There's also no syntax related to files. Such as `$_FILES` http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php. Your form should be a POST method, using a proper enctype. Along with the correct name attribute. All I see is an unassigned `$files` variable.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Plus, remove the `@` symbol(s) as already stated, they're error suppressors.

Comment: @ me if you need me, *moving on...*  cheers

Comment: Tried to remove the `@` symbol and added error reporting but I have no errors. I am getting my files from a directory, I have updated my code.

Comment: You're MIME body is missing a [`close-delimiter`](http://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup/2046#page-22). You should add `$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";` after the attachment loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like my code wasn't the problem. It was an issue with mailing it from info@mydomain.com. Changed `$from` variable to a gmail email address and it started sending emails again.